# Using enumerations in mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

Im creating a database design in MySQL Workbench. I want to have a enumarated table which holds some standard values. The values of the enumaration table needs to be linked to a row in my other table. So i have a table called 'club' which holds a row 'club_soort'. The row 'club_soort' needs to relate to the enumaration table.

Also, I want to use my tables (when i'm ready with my database design) into phpMyAdmin.

I understand the concept of enumaration, but I can't implement it. I hope someone can help me! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using enumerations, you should use what's known as a lookup or reference table. This table would contain your enumerations and be referenced as a foreign key by the parent table.

As an example, this would look like:

```
parent_table
------------                club
id                          ----
club_soort    ---------->   soort
```

Comment: So if I interpret this correctly: You create a row in your table ( in my case 'club_soort') which is an INT and relate this table to the enumaration table which consist of the rows 'id' and for example a 'name'?

Comment: @Marciano See my update. Data types aren't defined at the row, they're defined at the column

Answer (score 0):

ENUM values cannot be linked to any MySQL structures. It can contain only static data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about `primary keys`?
Being a relational database,  mysql uses `primary key`s and `indexes` to joint data the way you want to achieve.  
Primary keys join tables in an efficient way,  `PK` in the the origin or parent table and `FPK`, Foreign Primary Key in the related table.

When creating a table,  in `mysql workbench` or `phpmyadmin`,  define a `primary key`, just one per table and if needed indexes and if needed foreign keys.

Use `union` statements to join two or more tables.

Always use numeric keys data_type `INT` instead of natural, string keys.  Also make then `autoincrement` and `Not Null`.

mysqlworkbench has an exporting tool, which allows you to export each created table,  including their keys, indexes and cascading.  You can copy and paste to create tables in phpmyadmin.